# ES6/ES2015 Javascript incompatibility in old browser (Edge 13, IE11, etc)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a Javascript `<script>` snippet (try here: https://apploitech.github.io/embed-snippets) that executes `document.write(...)`, which writes a bunch of html and javascript functions into the DOM.

One of the Javascript functions does this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  console.log("DOMContentLoaded calling renderJobs");
  renderJobs(null, true, 1);
});
```

It works great for most browsers (Chrome, Safari, Edge 14/15), but on the following browsers, the message `Expected ')'` shows up in the IE/Edge Developer Tools console (as shown in screenshot below):

1. Edge 13 or below
2. IE11 or below

Any thoughts or best methods to debug? I tried going to char `1499` like the error message shows, but there is nothing there related to a `)`. Thanks!

[image: IE 11 Developer Tools console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default parameter is part of  ES6/ES2015 spec.

**Solution:**

```
function createPaginationButton(pagination_bar, page_num, isAppend) {
  if(isAppend === undefined) {
      isAppend = true;
   }
  ...
}
```

This is original function declaration from your snippet unsupported in older browsers:

```
function createPaginationButton(pagination_bar, page_num, isAppend = true) {
    console.log("createPaginationButton(): page_num = " + page_num);
    var page_num_box = document.createElement("a");
    page_num_box.innerHTML = page_num;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: bigless, you are a saint and genius. removing the "default parameter" did the trick along with removing `Number.isInteger()` which is not supported in old browsers. Thanks!